# Killing Processes Spawned by Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreman, procfile

I have the following `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
redis: bundle exec redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

Running `$ foreman start` starts up Unicorn, Redis and Sidekiq, but how should i stop them again?

Killing Foreman leaves all three up. I can see this using `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep redis | grep -v grep
    me           61560   0.0  0.0  2506784   1740 s000  S+    9:36am   0:01.28 redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf
$ ps aux | grep sidekiq  | grep -v grep
    me           61561   0.0  1.0  2683796 173284 s000  S+    9:36am   0:14.18 sidekiq 2.17.0 pathways [0 of 25 busy]
$ ps aux | grep unicorn | grep -v grep
    me           61616   0.0  0.2  2615284  28312 s000  S+    9:37am   0:00.06 unicorn worker[2] -p 5000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
    me           61615   0.0  0.2  2615284  27920 s000  S+    9:37am   0:00.06 unicorn worker[1] -p 5000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
    me           61614   0.0  0.2  2615284  27772 s000  S+    9:37am   0:00.06 unicorn worker[0] -p 5000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
    me           61559   0.0  1.0  2615284 160988 s000  S+    9:36am   0:09.87 unicorn master -p 5000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

**So obviously I can manually `kill` each process, but how can I kill all at once?** It doesn't seem like Foreman supports this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To kill them all with a one-liner:

```
$ kill $(ps aux | grep -E 'redis|sidekiq|unicorn' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me realize the rails port wasn't the only one I need to kill!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do this

```
$ killall "foreman: master"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Foreman supports this. I use [subcontractor](https://github.com/pitluga/subcontractor) and use it like so:

`web: subcontract --rbenv '1.9.3-p362' --chdir ../website --signal INT -- bundle exec thin start -p 3000`